# Networking fails in service, but only when app is closed

Tags: java, android, networking

I have a service defined that looks as such:

```java
public class phoneHome extends Service {
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "com.developer.app.notifchannel";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("started", "first run");
        new Thread(() -> {
            Log.i("started", "second run");
            URLConnection connection;
            AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "Entry").build();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30000);
                while (true) {
                    connection = new URL("https://url.com/blog/updates-3/feed").openConnection();
                    XmlPullParserFactory parserFactory;
                    parserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser parser;
                    parser = parserFactory.newPullParser();
                    parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, true);
                    parser.setInput(connection.getInputStream(), null);
                    int event = parser.getEventType();
                    String tag;
                    HashMap<String, Entry> entries = new HashMap<>();
                    Log.i("Starting", "parsing");
                    while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                        tag = parser.getName();
                        if (event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                            Log.i("Start tag", tag);
                            if (tag.equals("entry")) {
                                Entry temp = new Entry(parser);
                                MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
                                digest.reset();
                                String keyPreDigest = temp.entryLink + temp.entryUpdated;
                                String hash = Arrays.toString(digest.digest(keyPreDigest.getBytes()));
                                entries.put(hash, temp);
                            }
                        }
                        event = parser.next();
                    }
                    for (String hash : entries.keySet()) {
                        List<Entry> temp = db.entryDao().getByHash(hash);
                        if (temp.isEmpty()) {
                            db.entryDao().insertAll(entries.get(hash));
                            notify(Objects.requireNonNull(entries.get(hash)));
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(120000);
                }
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | XmlPullParserException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void notify(Entry entry) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = null;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(entry.entryId));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle(entry.entryTitle)
                .setContentText(entry.entrySummary)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        int id = entry.hashCode();
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

    }
}
```

The service runs in a separate process to make it function when the app isn't in the foreground:

```xml
        <service
            android:name=".phoneHome"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=".serviceproc"/>
```

Whenever I start the service while the app is open, it fetches the data needed and the notification fires. If the app is closed when the service tries to connect, it fails with:

```
W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to url.com/1.2.3.4:443
```

Specifically, at the line

```java
parser.setInput(connection.getInputStream(), null);
```

I don't know what to do at all, how do I get the networking to work even if the app isn't open?

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out!
The service also needs to be defined as needing the INTERNET permission.